# List comprehension and converting an argument to something else just isn't my thing

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have this working current code here which will take the user's arguments (example: !modify [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2.05, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2] will have the bot output [image: this]) then take the 13 numbers inside of the []s in all the sets of []s provided and multiply them together to output a new pair of []s with the same format as the ones provided in the arguments.

```
@client.command()
async def modify(ctx, *args):
    if ctx.channel.id != 850806578125864981:
        return
    else:
        sets = [] # stocking every sets found
        subset = [] #I call a 'set' a pair of brackets

        for arg in args:
            subset.append(float(''.join([car for car in arg if car.isnumeric() or car == '.']))) # just extracting the numerical part of the element
            if ']' in arg: #closing a set
                sets.append(subset)
                subset = [] # creating a new one

        output = [*sets[0]] # number of the first set

        for s in sets[1:]: # looping over every other sets
            for i in range(len(s)):
                output[i] *= s[i] # multiplying the numbers together

        embed=discord.Embed(title="g.stats helper", url="", description=f":white_check_mark: - Here is your new custom g.stat: \n\n **{output}**", color=0x77AC54)
        channel = client.get_channel(850806578125864981)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

But then I decided I also wanted the bot to recognize a certain set of words, like if "g.basic" or "g.factory" was provided in the !modify command's arguments, the bot would recognize it as if you entered "[18.25,1.4,.1,1,2,.2,1,4.5,1,1,1,15,1]" or "[72, 1, .1, .7, 2, .2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, .1, 1]"  (example: "!modify g.basic [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2]" would be like saying "!modify [18.25,1.4,.1,1,2,.2,1,4.5,1,1,1,15,1] [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2]" which would normally have the bot output "[54.75, 2.8, 0.2, 2.0, 4.0, 0.4, 2.0, 9.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 60.0, 2.0]").

The problem is I don't know how to have the bot recognize certain words like "g.basic", here is my failed attempt below (It would be amazing if someone not only gave the answer but explained in somewhat depth of what they did to solve the issue/the meaning of the code they implemented, that would be great!):

```
@client.command()
async def modify(ctx, *args):
    if ctx.channel.id != 850828323135160341:
        return
    else:

        lookup = {
    "g.basic": "[18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]",
    "g.factory": "[72, 1, .1, .7, 2, .2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, .1, 1]"
}
        new_args = [lookup.get(arg, arg) for arg in args]

        sets = [] # stocking every sets found
        subset = [] #I call a 'set' a pair of brackets

        for arg in new_args:
            subset.append(float(''.join([car for car in arg if car.isnumeric() or car == '.']))) # just extracting the numerical part of the element
            if ']' in arg: #closing a set
                sets.append(subset)
                subset = [] # creating a new one

        output = [*sets[0]] # number of the first set

        for s in sets[1:]: # looping over every other sets
            for i in range(len(s)):
                output[i] *= s[i] # multiplying the numbers together

        embed=discord.Embed(title="g.stats helper", url="", description=f":white_check_mark: - Here is your new custom g.stat: \n\n **{output}**", color=0x77AC54)
        channel = client.get_channel(850806578125864981)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I get this [image: error].
For anyone that takes the time to read this and help me, you are amazing! I've been looking for a solution for longer than a day now and my brain is really starting to fry.

Comment: Could you try to put the different inputs and associated desired outputs more clearly ? I see one example but I don't get the full picture

Comment: To fix this specific bug, change your line there `[car for car in arg if car.isnumeric() or car == '.']`, because you try to convert to float even when you get a dot `'.'`. While you should keep both parts of the number together (18.25 should Not be split by the dot)

Comment: Any chance of distilling that to a **minimal** [mre] that focuses on the problem? Not just a *code dump*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't have the time to setup a discord channel and setup a project to work with it but I can give you some code that should work. You'll just have to adapt it to you're situation.

Ok so you're getting input as a string from the command `!modify`. And you are wanting to have shortcuts to save on typing. For example `g.basic` should be the same as typing out `[18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]`. Cool makes sense.

So here is what I would do.

```
lookup = {
    "g.basic": "[18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]",
    "g.factory": "[72, 1, .1, .7, 2, .2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, .1, 1]"
}

# Using a mock input that would be similar to what you're getting as input
mock_input = ["g.basic", "[3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2]"]


# First lets replace any shortcuts with the actual value they point to
# This takes mock_input and maps it to a lambda that if 'arg' is a key in lookup it replaces it with the value
# if it's not in lookup then just return the original input
processed_input = list(map(lambda arg: arg if arg not in lookup else lookup[arg], mock_input))

args_values = []

# Now lets get all numbers in args and convert it to a list of floats
for arg in processed_input:
    # List comprehension cause this is python
    # Split the string by ', ' cause thats how they are seperated in the string
    # arg[1: -1] will remove the leading and trailing '[' and ']' so we dont have to worry about them
    # Then we convert all strings in this list to floats and add it to the 'args_values' list
    args_values.append([float(value) for value in arg[1: -1].split(', ')])

# Now zip the inputs together to match first elements together then second elements and so on
# Then map them to multiple them together and return the new list of multiplied values
print (list(map(lambda values: values[0] * values[1], zip(*args_values))))
```

Comment: No matter what I put as arguments in the modify command, now I always receive the answer of "[54.75, 2.8, 0.2, 2.0, 4.0, 0.4, 2.0, 9.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 60.0, 2.0]"

Comment: Remember that my code has mock data in it. You need to replace `mock_input` with the input you are getting from discord. If you can figure it out show me how you used my code in your script.